# combining results of two find commands linux

Tags: find, directory-structure

I have a set of configuration backups that are organized like

```
backup/site1/10-11-2019
backup/site1/11-11-2019
backup/site1/12-11-2019

backup/site2/10-11-2019
backup/site2/11-11-2019
backup/site2/12-11-2019

backup/site3/10-11-2019
backup/site3/11-11-2019
backup/site3/12-11-2019
```

I need to list the configuration files that are less than specific size for one particular date for all sites. In a way so that I could combine following two commands from backup directory

```
find . -type d -name "11-11-2019"
find . -name "*.cfg" -size +500c
```

Please help me combining these two commands

Answer (score 0):

You can use `-path` instead of `-name`:

```
find . -type f -path '*/11-11-2019/*.cfg' -size +500c
```

Comment: very nice suggestion but for some reason it's not returning anything tried both
`find . -type f -path '*/11-11-2019/*.cfg' -size -50c`
`find . -type f -path '*/11-11-2019/*' -size -50c`

Comment: you're missing the `*` before and after the directory.

Comment: This one works
 `find .  \( -type f -and -path '*/2019-11-11/*' \) -name "*.cfg" -size -50c -print`

Comment: it is automatically replacing * in my comment

Comment: not sure why \( \) is needed

Answer (score -1):

```
find . -type d -name "11-11-2019" -a -name "*.cfg" -size +500c
```

-a stands for AND condition

Comment: this won't find anything as `*.cfg` is not of `type d` and name cannot be both `11-11-2019` and `*.cfg`